# Android: Testing app on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a tablet Genesis GT-7240, Android 4.1.1, Kernel 3.0.36+.

My manifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

It is a simple app, using Google Maps and so it must be compiled with API GOOGLE.

As I testing in a real device, I checked 'Unknown sources', copied the compiled apk into 'download' folder of the tablet, and I tried install it as I always usually do.

However, has a message

X App not instaled.

Another tablet, which has **Android 3.2, the same app works perfectly**.

Is there a issue with Android 4.1 and Api Google compilation?

[Editing]

My manifest.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="MY_PACKAGE_HERE"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<permission android:name="MY_PACKAGE_HERE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="MY_PACKAGE_HERE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/> 
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="MY_PACKAGE_HERE.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="MY_APY_KEY_HERE"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My activity_main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

My MainActivity.java:

```
package MY_PACKAGE_HERE;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity { 
      private GoogleMap gm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
        if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
          SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
          gm = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        }
        else {
          int requestCode = 10;
          Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
          dialog.show();
        }
    }//onCreate
    //*****************************

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not visible if the problem is due to Maps. However Google Maps API 2 is part of Google Play Services. You don't have to compile with Google APIs. You have to make sure if your device has Google Play Services installed and updated.

Comment: Dear Sharj, is it not enough to link my project to google play library and compile them together?

Comment: You also need Play Services. Most devices already have it. Just check if your device has it or not, or you can install from Play Store as well https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

Comment: Thank you, Sharj, I didn't have it installed in my tablet. I downloaded that app, but still the same.